# How to do a circular workflow

Tags: mvvmcross

I want to model a circular workflow, so starting at View/ViewModel StepA, than StepB and so on.
If the user reaches the end and everything is fine, data will be processed somehow and the user should brought back to StepA, but now with a new StepAViewModel instance **and a clean navigation stack**. 
I do a simple .navigate(..) to StepA which seems ok, but the navigation stack is filled up so you can step back hundred times, but this is definetly wrong in my app. Only stepping back to the beginning of the current process is allowed.

Thanks for helping

With best regards

Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if you already found the solution for this but just in case anyone finds in the same spot as you:*

I'm not sure where you want it to go when you go back from Step A, but after you workflow is done you could use a `MvxPopToRootPresentationHint` to pop everything so you end up in your root view, or `MvxPopPresentationHint` to go to a specific view, and from there you just navigate to your Step A, in this manner the only thing before Step A is your Root view (or your specific view if you use the other hint).

To use the hint, you just do this (I've set `animated:false` in the hint but you can set `true` if you want the back-navigation-animation to happen):

`await mvxNavigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxPopToRootPresentationHint(false))`

More info in [Requesting presentation changes](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters#requesting-presentation-changes) and [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross/Presenters/Hints) you can see different types of hints.
HIH.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, yes I will try it.

With best regards

Gerhard